# How did Baudrillard justify the existence of a "fundamental" reality?

Tags: postmodernism, hyperreality, baudrillard

> The postmodern semiotic concept of hyperreality was contentiously coined by Baudrillard in Simulacra and Simulation. Baudrillard defined "hyperreality" as "the generation by models of a real without origin or reality"

If we take the hyperreality idea seriously, then how could we ever verify a "real reality" when we are almost always influenced in our culture and beliefs. Or, in otherwords, how could one say they'd be unbiased enough to say that they have the investigative power needed to confirm an existence of a  real reailty?

Comment: Which summarizes to *How do we make sure Baudrillard is wrong?* 